# Which method will excute while dismissing the popover by tapping on the view

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

Hi in my application whenever i tap on the view. The launched popover will get dismiss automatically. May i know which method will execute for getting this behavior.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Make your main view controller the delegate for the popover controller and implement the – popoverControllerDidDismissPopover: method. Take a look at Apple's documentation for help.

[Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009307)